# Google Sheets requesting access to a users sheets for public sheet

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I'm developing a Java app which will connect and read data from a google sheet that's public.
When the app is ran for the first time it asks the user for permission to access their google sheets. The app won't be reading anything from the users own sheets, just the public one so not sure how to stop it asking.

I'm requesting the data using

```
private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = GoogleAPI.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    if (in == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    }
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
}
```

and

```
public ArrayList<Template> loadTemplates() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    ArrayList<Template> templateList = new ArrayList();
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    final String spreadsheetId = "****";
    final String range = "****";
    Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
    ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
            .get(spreadsheetId, range)
            .execute();
    List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
    if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No data found.");
    } else {
        for (List row : values) {
            / /Code here
        }
    }
    return templateList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switched it to use the API rather than oAuth as I only read.

Added the below to the methods.

```
HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer = request -> {
        request.setInterceptor(intercepted -> intercepted.getUrl().set("key", API_KEY));
    };
    Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, httpRequestInitializer)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may have the same question.
Here`s the method to read data from public Google Sheet with Google Cloud Platform API key only.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
            List<List<Object>> result = loadData();
            for (List row : result) {
                System.out.println(row);
            }
        }

    public static List<List<Object>> loadData() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
             JacksonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
             String APPLICATION_NAME = ".";
//Insert here your API key created by Google Cloud Platform
             String API_KEY = "";
            
            final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            //Insert here Google Sheet ID            
            final String spreadsheetId = "";
            //D to read all data in sheet
            final String range = "A2:D";
    
            HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer = request -> {
                request.setInterceptor(intercepted -> intercepted.getUrl().set("key", API_KEY));
            };
            Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, httpRequestInitializer)
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();
    
            ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
                    .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                    .execute();
            List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
            if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("No data found.");
            }
            return values;
        }
```